# How to apply action to any image using "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, this, bxslider

I'm beginner with functions using "this" object.

I created a slider showing images miniature size.
On mouseover one of those images, I want it to be shown full in another div (#flyerShow).

The slider containing images is in div #bxslider

On mouseover an image of the slider, I launch a function onMouseOver() :

```
$('#bxslider img').mouseover(function() {
  onMouseOver();
});/**/
```

here is my function onMouseOver() :

```
function onMouseOver()
{
  var imageToShow = '<img src="'+this.src+" />'
  $('#flyerShow').html(imageToShow );
}
```

How can I get the image src I mouseover, and use it in my function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you have to do:

```
$('#bxslider img').mouseover(onMouseOver);
```

You were losing the `this` value because you were calling onMouseOver() with a new context.

Comment: thanks a lot !it' difficult to see I'm loosing 'this' value, but I will study that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` from the first to second function:

```
$('#bxslider img').mouseover(function() {
  onMouseOver(this);
});

function onMouseOver(elem)
{
  var imageToShow = '<img src="'+elem.src+" />'
  $('#flyerShow').html(imageToShow );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.call( this, args... )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass `this`:

```
onMouseOver.call( this );
```

Doing it this way allows you to transfer the scope without having to pass it as an argument. If you want to pass any extra parameters to `onMouseOver`, they just follow `this`, one-by-one.

Another related function is [`.apply( this, argsArray )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) where instead of passing the parameters one-by-one, you can just pass an array containing the parameters.

Comment: very interesting but difficult to understand "this" and associate to object ...
What kind of "extra parameters" could I pass also additionnaly to "this", in this case of beeing hover an image ? (to understand better your information) :
onMouseOver.call(this);

Comment: @Nonoseki if your function accepted any other parameters (eg. alert takes 1 parameter - the message to alert), you'd pass them in there

Answer (score 0):

You want to call onMouseOver passing in this. So

```
onMouseOver(this);
```

Then in your onMouseOver function add a parameter calling it whatever you want, and from there you can use jquery to get the image src

```
$(this).attr("src");
```